# How to make a responsive website render the desktop version on a mobile?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, instead of trying to be responsive, I want to show the desktop version of the website (obviously scaled / zoomed out) on the mobile and then let the user zoom in and out to look at the site.

I want this as an option instead of showing a responsive version of the website.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: you mean, you want to show `desktop` version in `mobile` too? and don't want to see `responsive version` ?

Comment: The easiest way is to have your mobile styling is a separate style sheet, then if the user clicks to show full website then remove that link to the mobile.css

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, kind of problematic as things use "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2" etc.     Unless I can for things to be large or something?

Comment: Hmmm - yeah I see what you mean - maybe the meta tag solutions might be a better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use 'viewport' meta tag

For example to display mobile site always in desktop resolution you can use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280,initial-scale=1">
```

To dynamically add mobile resizing you can do something like

```
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name = "viewport";
meta.content = "width=1280,initial-scale="+window.innerWidth/1280;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have an effect with bootstrap

Comment: The effect will only be noticeable when viewing through a mobile device. Resizing the browser will not trigger this.

Comment: You have to replace the bootstrap default meta tag, i success to do it with getbootstrap.com in chrome developer tools

Comment: any idea how to zoom out so the website fits on the mobile by default?

Comment: @KeithNicholas by removing the viewport tag completely, you will end up with the desktop website, squeezed into the viewport, on which the user can then pinch to zoom. You shouldn't need to use javascript for this

Comment: @guy If he remove the tag after page loading it's not changed in some devices, also, some mobile browser will use width=device-width as default value

Comment: Why remove it after loading? You want to remove it from your source template, so that it is not present when the page loads.

Comment: I guess from their question he dosen't want to touch template code

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the `viewport` meta tag to achieve this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have an effect with bootstrap

Comment: The effect will only be noticeable when viewing through a mobile device. Resizing the browser will not trigger this.

Comment: Ahh, ok.   Upvoted for that piece of advice! However just removing didn't solve it,  fixing the width did.